# WASM (without Blazor) is very slow for large number arrays

Tags: c#, webassembly

I'm trying to use my c# code in my JavaScript by publishing the c# code as webassembly. It works for the most part, except for large number arrays.

In my c# code, I have a simple method like this:

```cs
        [JSInvokable]
        public static double[] Test(double[] a, double[] b)
        {
            return new double[];
        }
```

then I publish the js and in my JavaScript, I call the method:

```js
var temp = dotnet.MyTest.test(a, b);
```

where a and b are number arrays. Each has 1 million elements.

It took about 40 seconds for `temp` to get the return value. A direct c# call to the same test method would return immediately.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't know, but that's exactly what I would expect. And then: millions of values of anything doesn't make much sense to me in a GUI.

Comment: Arrays are marshalled (passed) between .NET and JavaScript by copying. You can avoid this  by using Span<double> or ArraySegment<double>. These types appear on the JS side as `MemoryView`, a JS class that's part of the .NET WASM runtime. Check the [.NET Interop page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/dotnet-interop?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Why are you doing this in the browser at all though? Not only is RAM limited but the .NET JIT compiler can speed up at least some math operations by vectorizing the code. There's only a single thread which means you can't use PLINQ or Parallel.For to process large arrays.

Comment: We have common code for both desktop and web app to do some analysis on plot data. That's why I'm trying to reuse the code, instead of rewriting in JS. Thanks for the info. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

When passing a `double[]` from Javascript to WASM.

We need to do something called marshalling of the data.

In this case, the default behavior for marshalling of a JS array into a `double[]` is to copy the array.

That is pretty slow.

The only way I know that might be possible for you to achieve fast interop with  huge arrays of `Number`, would be for you to:

- Pre allocate a large array from dotnet.
- Pin the array
- Pass the memory address from dotnet to JS
- Wrap the wrap the address + size in a DataView (using the WASM memory object)
- Write to the DataView
- Call the DotNet method using offsets and size pointers, and construct Span
- Profit